# I get Unresolved reference: dismiss when i try to dismiss the alert dialog android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-alertdialog

When i try to call `dismiss()` on my messageBoxBuilder but i get `Unresolved reference: dismiss` , i tried to call it on messageBoxView and to change `setCancelable()` to `true` but same thing happened.

```
fun create_Alert_Dialog(){
    //Alert dialog builder
    val messageBoxView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.layout_dialog,null)
    //Alert dialog builder
    val messageBoxBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this).setView(messageBoxView)
    //Setting undissmissable
    messageBoxBuilder.setCancelable(false)
    //Show
    messageBoxBuilder.create().show()
    bt4 = messageBoxView.findViewById(R.id.bt4)
    bt4.setOnClickListener {
        Lose()
        messageBoxBuilder.dismiss()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to rewrite your code like this

```
fun create_Alert_Dialog(){
    //Alert dialog builder
    val messageBoxView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.layout_dialog,null)
    //Alert dialog builder
    val messageBoxBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setView(messageBoxView)
        //Setting undissmissable
        .setCancelable(false)
        //Show
        .create().apply {
            messageBoxView.findViewById(R.id.bt4).setOnClickListener {
                Lose()
                this.dismiss()
            }

            show()
        }
}
```